# Swift 3 - Add existing UISearchBar to UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchBar` that is already integrated into my UI (colors, constraints, position, etc.), however I now want to add an autocomplete table using the Google Places API.

I found several tutorials online (namely: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_a_results_controller) but they all require creating a `UISearchController` programmatically, which already has a `UISearchBar` in it.

Is there a way to initialize a `UISearchController` (by maybe overriding an initializer in a custom `UISearchController` class?) and pass in a `UISearchBar`?

If not, what would be the best way to implement a autocomplete search results with a pre-existing search bar?

(Note: I have a scope bar attached to the search bar, so I don't want to just implement the full-screen Google Places Autocomplete controller)

Comment: Use UISearchBar delegates and have a tableView below your search bar and reload the tableView with search results thats all :) If you clearly look at UISearchController it does not do any magic under the hood infact it does not provide any code either all it provides is a search results tableView controller hooked to search bar which you will have to hook it up manually thats all :)